# TypeError: res.getHeader is not a function in NextJS API

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am trying to create a web application with NextJS 13 with TypeScript, Next Auth v4, Prisma (with a SQLite database for development) and OpenAI.

The console displays an error whenever I access to the API endpoint with the following message:

> error - TypeError: res.getHeader is not a function
>
> at setCookie (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/utils.js:11:49)

I have detected that the code fails whenever it tries to assign the session variable with `getServerSession()` at this line:

```js
export async function GET(
    req: NextApiRequest, 
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions) // <-- here it fails
    const sessionErrors = checkSessionErrors(session, req.url);
    if (sessionErrors) return sessionErrors;

    // rest of the code
}
```

I have been researching over the internet and I found some issues related to a Webpack middleware. But I am not using any middleware.

I have tried also replacing the code to look like this:

```js
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    const session = await getServerSession() // not sure how to fill this now
    const sessionErrors = checkSessionErrors(session, req.url);
    if (sessionErrors) return sessionErrors;

    // rest of the code
    // return stuff with NextResponse.json()
}
```

Not sure how to proceed now, any suggested actions on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getServerSession` expects `NextApiRequest` and `NextApiResponse` arguments. I solved this by adding the `getHeader` and `setHeader` functions to `NextResponse`:

```js
export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const session = await getServerSession(
    req as unknown as NextApiRequest,
    {
      ...res,
      getHeader: (name: string) => res.headers?.get(name),
      setHeader: (name: string, value: string) => res.headers?.set(name, value),
    } as unknown as NextApiResponse,
    authOptions
  );
}
```

Comment: this is not working for me can you explain the same a little more, please?

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to pass the req & res in when using the app router. it works with just the authOptions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Despite its brevity, this is what worked for me.

Comment: Jon, can you explain your fix way in brief please?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76572072/20943696), I gave it a try and found that it works like a charm. Therefore, I am sharing my code:

```
// next: 14.0.3
// next-auth: 4.24.5

// Change the path to where your `authOptions` is
import { authOptions } from '@/utils/auth'

import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'

export async function POST() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  if (!session) {
    return Response.json({ message: 'You must be logged in.' }, { status: 401 })
  }

  try {
    const result = someOperations() // ...

    return Response.json(result)
  } catch (err) {
    return Response.json(err, { status: 500 })
  }
}
```

Here are the relevant docs:

1. [NextJS Route Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)
2. [NextAuth getServerSession](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#getserversession)

Updated on 2023/12/17:

I found I've made a mistake. We can't export `authOptions` from a route file because of NextJS's rule. Therefore, I modified the code and changed the import path to `@/utils/auth`.