# TypeError: res.getHeader is not a function in next-auth

Tags: reactjs, next.js, typeerror, next-auth

I am working on the `next 13` with the `next-auth`. I am having the error `TypeError: res.getHeader is not a function` when I am validating the API using the `getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)` to check user is logged in or not

Below is my APIs

**users/routes.ts**

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { connectMongoDB } from "@/lib/mongodb";
import User from "@/models/user"
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth';
import { authOptions } from '../auth/[...nextauth]/route';
export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {

  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
  if (!session) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "You must be logged in.", status: 401 });

  }
  try {
    await connectMongoDB();
    const users = await User.find();
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "", status: 200, data: users })
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Error occured..", status: 500 })
  }
}
```

**auth/[...nextauth]/routes.js**

```js
import { connectMongoDB } from "@/lib/mongodb";
import User from "@/models/user";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Email and password",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;
        try {
          await connectMongoDB();
          const user = await User.findOne({ email })

          if (!user) {
            return null;
          }
          const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
          if (!passwordMatch) {
            return null;
          }
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error', error)
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/",
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I have tried the `getServerSession(authOptions)` and its worked but dont idea it is the correct way or not.

Please help me to understand/fix this issue with the correct way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: res.getHeader is not a function in NextJS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76319880/typeerror-res-getheader-is-not-a-function-in-nextjs-api)

Comment: Consider raising a ticket here https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues

Comment: that answer is not work for me

Comment: I need to know in API what option is a valid way to use `getServerSession(authOptions)` OR `getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)`

Comment: I think both are valid. Is seems it's a bug

Comment: bug from next-auth?

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSession(authOptions)` works perfectly fine.

If you want to include the requests, you have to add `headers` to the `getServerSession` function along with `authOptions`.