# Setting cookies inside next-auth

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I'd like to introduce refresh token rotation to my app. After hitting `/token/refresh` endpoint I receive `accessToken` and `refreshToken` as a cookie. For `accessToken` I can just do `token.accessToken = rotatedAccess` inside JWT callback. So the **question** is can I somehow set `refreshToken` cookie inside `authOptions`? It sometimes works, sometimes throws `Error: Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler`, which I guess has something to do with this happening during RSC fetch/loading. Saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69704737/11849553) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76319880/typeerror-res-getheader-is-not-a-function-in-nextjs-api) (still get `'res.setHeader is not a function'`), but doesn't seem to work, unless I messed something up.